# Wording on an English marriage register from Somerset in 1834

Tags: marriage-records, 1830s, somerset

I am confused by the word "resident" when referring to the groom - here in context:

```
Henry Chapman (a bachelor) resident of this parish
and Grace Cummins (a spinster) of this parish
```

To me it is implying that there is a difference in residence between Henry and Grace - does it mean that Henry is just staying there and not part of the parish - neither as far as I know were baptised in the parish (Milverton).

The document source is: Somerset Heritage Service; Taunton, Somerset, England; Somerset Parish Records, 1538-1914; Reference Number: D\P\milv/2/1/13

It is page 100 item 300

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word *resident* at that time implied ownership.

A resident of the parish will have owned property.  They own a residence.

Being described simply as *of the parish* indicates the person lived there but did not own the residence.  A spinster, as likely as not, still lived with her parents.

I have a number of relatives who lived in or near Milverton around this time.  Some are labelled resident others not.  I have tracked down some property ownership records online which seem to confirm this distinction.